# Size of Sweave Output

Tags: beamer, sweave, r

I am very new to LaTeX and Sweave, and I am just playing around with getting some output. That said, the "output" I am getting is very large in size (physcially on the page).  For example, one output from a 2x3 crosstab takes up a whole 8.5x11 page.  If I try to use the same output in a beamer presentation, maybe 30% of the output fits on 1 slide.

Simply, when pushing output from R using Sweave, how can I control the size of the output?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:  Below is a code snipped within my .Rnw file (before Sweave processing)

```
<<echo=FALSE>>=
cat("Education by Induced")
cat("\n")
CrossTable(infert$education, infert$induced, expected = TRUE, format="SPSS")
@
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\scalebox{}` command that comes with the `graphicx` package. E.g., with

```
\scalebox{0.7}{%
\begin{tabular}{...}
...
\end{tabular}}
```

your text will be printed at 70%.

This will only work if you use a Sweave chunk to create an external file (say, `tab1.tex`) and then include it in the LATEX file using an `\include` or `\input` statement, not by printing it directly into you master file with `results=tex`.

**Update:**

Given my comment and your updated question, I would suggest to look at the [Design](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Design/index.html) package which offers convenient LaTeX export of nice-looking Tables, see `summary.formula()`. Again, the idea would be to write a Table generated this way into a TeX file, and then `\input` it into your master `Rnw` file. You can look at [Statistical Reporting, Linking S Output with Report Documents, Literate Programming, Managing Analyses, and Documenting Programs and Data](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/StatReport) for more detailed illustrations.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I edited my post above to show a code snippet.  I am using the gmodels package and the function CrossTable, which to the best of my knowledge can not be used with results=tex, however, I am very new to this game.

Comment: @Btibert3 Ah, so I think my solution will not work in this case. Still, you can try to write a "texified" output from `CrossTable()` into a file and then `\input` it into your Sweave doc. I remember doing this way with automatic reports. But, looking at the output from `CrossTable()` with the `format="SPSS"` option, I can imagine this will be tricky to convert the raw table to a `tabular`. I offer an alternative way in my updated response.